Can I Efficiently Map This Matrix to a Vector with Numpy Functions?
Suppose I have a 27x27 ndarray of integers A that I want to reduce to a 25-length vector b such that it contains the following values (in some order):
numpy.sum(A[0:9, 0:9])
numpy.sum(A[0:9, 9:18])
numpy.sum(A[0:9, 18:27])
numpy.sum(A[9:18, 0:9])
numpy.sum(A[9:18, 18:27])
numpy.sum(A[18:27, 0:9])
numpy.sum(A[18:27, 9:18])
numpy.sum(A[18:27, 18:27])
numpy.sum(A[9:12, 9:12])
numpy.sum(A[9:12, 12:15])
numpy.sum(A[9:12, 15:18])
numpy.sum(A[12:15, 9:12])
numpy.sum(A[12:15, 15:18])
numpy.sum(A[15:18, 9:12])
numpy.sum(A[15:18, 12:15])
numpy.sum(A[15:18, 15:18])
numpy.sum(A[12:13, 12:13])
numpy.sum(A[12:13, 13:14])
numpy.sum(A[12:13, 14:15])
numpy.sum(A[13:14, 12:13])
numpy.sum(A[13:14, 14:15])
numpy.sum(A[14:15, 12:13])
numpy.sum(A[14:15, 13:14])
numpy.sum(A[14:15, 14:15])
numpy.sum(A[13:14, 13:14])

In other words, each colored square in the below matrix A (see "Coloring image") should have its elements summed. Each sum should be an element in vector b.

I want to convert a given A into b very efficiently, so I want to do this via numpy functions, not by manually computing the sum of each square block and not by doing extra arithmetic operations (I know I can flatten the A into a vector and convert it to b via a matrix multiplication, but that requires more multiplications).

Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please edit your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the full text of any errors or tracebacks, all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a minimal reproducible example.

Please show how you can calculate b "inefficiently" first and why you think that method is insufficient.

You could reshape and swapaxes to divide the array into the (3,3,9,9) blocks, and do the sum on those.  Or use sliding_window_view.  But subdividing the central block will require additional steps.  Basically, operations that create equal sized blocks can often be done in 'vectorized/whole_array' manner, but differing shapes will require some sort of (python level) iteration.

There is no chance to make that fast in pure Python nor even Numpy. Numpy is mean to be fast for relatively large arrays. Each Numpy function call has a significant overhead and I think many calls are needed to do that in Numpy. The key is to use a compiled code. In a compiled language like C/C++/Rust, this computation should take far less time than a np.sum call, whatever the input, and possibly less than any Numpy call. Numba and Cython can also help to do the same thing certainly more easily (possibly with a slightly higher overhead, and initial JIT one).

Just to give an example, all np.sum calls takes at least 3 µs on my machine (even to add just 2 numbers). During this time, my i5-9600KF 5-year old mid-end CPU can do 54_000 scalar integer add/mul operations, or 27_000 scalar floating-point ones. For SIMD ones (operations on vectors), it is typically 4 times this, so >100_000 numbers in 3 µs (just using 1 core).
